# subclipse acting weird

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I commit something (new files) in subclipse using eclipse indigo and immediately it shows them as incoming and asks me to update. It tells me that I modified them!

This seems strange to me in subversive when you commit something, it's commited it doesn't show those same files you just commmited as needed to be updated if no one changed them.

Any ideas?

Comment: perform a `cleanup` and then commit.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in subclipse. Sometimes after commit it just seems to override the files you  committed from your workspace with the previous version of those files from the repository.

I found this old bug in the issue tracker (http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=77), which seems to be related, but i'm not sure if this is the same bug.

Comment: that seems to be for an old version and that bug was already resolved. I still get this systematically. Commit some new files, and as soon as I committed them, it shows them as incoming.

Comment: @Ayrad, just to make sure, you did do "Help > Check for Updates" to make sure you have the newest version of Subclipse, yes?

Comment: @MatrixFrog - No updates found. It's just weird it's as if it thinks I'm a different user and asks me to update with my changes that I have just commited